# CRA + Inversify @inject Module parse failed: Unexpected character '@'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, constructor, create-react-app, inversifyjs

This is the error that I get

./src/core/providers/todoApi/TodoApiProvider.ts 10:14
Module parse failed: Unexpected character '@' (10:14)
File was processed with these loaders:

- ./node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/@pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin/loader/index.js
- ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js
  You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
  | class TodoApiProvider {

> constructor(@inject(TYPES.HttpClient)
> |   httpClient) {
> |     this.httpClient = void 0;

`TodoApiProvider.ts`

```
class DefaultTodoApiProvider implements TodoApiProvider {
  private httpClient: HttpClient;

  // @inject(TYPES.HttpClient) return error
  constructor(@inject(TYPES.HttpClient) httpClient: HttpClient) {
    this.httpClient = Dependency.get(TYPES.HttpClient);
  }

  async getTodoById(id: string) {
    const data = await this.httpClient.get(
      `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/${id}`
    );

    return data;
  }
}

decorate(injectable(), TodoApiProvider);

export default DefaultTodoApiProvider;
```

If I put `@inject(TYPES.HttpClient)` above `private httpClient: HttpClient;` it will get another error `Cannot access 'TYPES' before initialization`.

`.babelrc`

```
{
  "presets": [
    ...,
    "@babel/preset-typescript"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    ...,
    "babel-plugin-transform-typescript-metadata",
    ["@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators", { "legacy": true }],
    ["@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties", { "loose": true }]
  ],
  "env": {
    "test": {
      "plugins": [
        "transform-require-context",
        "babel-plugin-transform-typescript-metadata",
        "babel-plugin-parameter-decorator"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

`tsconfig.js`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": false,
  },
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Both [stage 1](https://github.com/wycats/javascript-decorators/blob/696232bbd997618d603d6577848d635872f25c43/README.md) and [stage 2](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-decorators/blob/1f10a6bee1c8df1c43cc60be73ce8362f849e2d1/README.md) decorator proposals do not support parameter decorators. The `@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators` which implements the proposals do not know how to handle parameter decorators. As a result, the error message `Unexpected character '@'` was produced. Only Typescript is aware of [parameter decorators](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html#parameter-decorators).

I use Next.js not CRA but I believe it is the same problem. For Next.js, I solved this problem by installing `ts-loader` and configuring the Next.js webpack configuration to use ts-loader before babel-loader.

The snippet below is specific to Next.js. I reference it to clarify my point.

```
config.module.rules.forEach((rule) => {
  if (rule.test instanceof RegExp && rule.test.test(".ts")) {
    if (Array.isArray(rule.use)) {
      rule.use.push("ts-loader");
    } else {
      rule.use = [rule.use, "ts-loader"];
    }
  }
});
```

About accesing TYPES before initialization, I did not investigate why it happens since it is solved by using `ts-loader` as well when fixing the first issue.